# Why can't anonymous users see what a regular read user sees?

Tags: permissions, web-application, anonymous-authentication

Regular read user:

[image]

Anonymous user:
[image]

I get why they wouldn't have any way to edit anything, but how come they don't see the quick launch or the doc lib web part?  What can they see / do?

Comment: what permission you give the Anonymous user?

Answer (score 1):

thats because anonymous uses are still based on limmited access.

have you disabled -> "limmited-access user permission lockdown mode" its a feature within sitecollection that is enabled by default. That should solve your issue.

if its still an issue follow this simple guide to setting up anonymous access to your site collection.... its a few areas that you need to change  if you havent already!

http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/10/15/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-to-a-sharepoint-2013-site/

Comment: What about SP 2013 Foundation?  That feature does not seem to exist. I found a couple of posts that talk about disabling it via PowerShell, but in Foundation, the feature is not recognized.  Apparently you could disable it in 2010 Foundation.

Comment: Anyway to deactivate "limited access user permission lockdown mode" in 2013 Foundation?

Comment: as your using foundation you need to follow this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-foundation-help/grant-permissions-to-anonymous-users-HA101805390.aspx